# Regex doesn't work with multi line

Tags: php, regex, multiline

```
$regpattern4 = "!<media:description type='plain'> (.*) <\/media:description>!";
```

I am parsing an XML document. The above Regex works if there are no line breaks in the description, but how do I make it work even if there are line breaks?

Comment: Consider using a DOM for parsing XML. It will handle the edge cases far better than a regex will.

Comment: You don't really need the backslash before the forward slash...

Answer (score 4):

The manual page "[Pattern Modifiers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)" might interest you, about that, especially the **s** (`PCRE_DOTALL`) modifier :

> If this modifier is set, **a dot
>   metacharacter in the pattern matches
>   all characters, including newlines**.
>   Without it, newlines are excluded.
>   This modifier is equivalent to Perl's
>   /s modifier. A negative class such as
>   [^a] always matches a newline
>   character, independent of the setting
>   of this modifier.

Your regex will become something like this :

```
$regpattern4 = "!<media:description type='plain'> (.*) <\/media:description>!s";
```

Note I added the '`s`' modifier after the end delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using regex to parse xml? Why not use simplexml_load_string to load the XML document and "walk" through it. It will be less error prone than complex regex statements, unless you are looking to do a simple replace.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 preg_match("/pattern/s", $text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the [`s` (DOTALL) modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

```
$regpattern4 = "!(.*)<\/media:description>!s";
```